# Mostrar detalles de un producto en modal con PHP y Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, bootstrap, modal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito mostrar en un modal de Bootstrap la información especifica de un producto al hacer click en el botón 'ver más'. El problema que tengo es que al abrir el modal se muestran todos los datos del producto pero no logro que se muestre la imagen del producto (solamente se muestra el nombre de la imagen pero no la foto en si).

*El código del botón 'ver mas'*: al botón le agregue el atributo 'data-producto' en donde, a través de php, le paso los datos del producto que están en la base de datos.

```
<div class="card-footer p-4 pt-0 border-top-0 bg-transparent">
        <button class="text-center btn btn-dark detalle-prod" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#detalle-prod" data-product = "<strong>Producto:</strong> <?php echo $producto['nombre'] . '<br>'. '<strong>Precio:</strong> $'. $producto['precio'] . '<br> <strong>Descripcion:</strong> ' . $producto['descripcion'] . '<br> <strong>Imagen del producto:</strong> ' . $producto['imagen']?>">Ver más</button>
  </div>
```

*Este es el código js*: capturo el boton 'ver mas', le agrego el evento click y luego en la variable producto guardo el valor del atributo 'data-product' que tiene el boton 'ver mas'. Luego capturo el modal (que va a disparar dicho boton) y al mismo le agrego el contenido de la variable producto con la funcion html() de jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.detalle-prod').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let producto = $(this).attr('data-product');
        $('#detail-prod').html(`<p> ${producto}</p>`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Pero no estas filtrando los resultados.. ahora ${producto} puedes hacerle un console.log y decirnos que tiene?

Comment: El console.log me muestra la información de cada producto. En cuanto a filtrar datos, sé que lo puedo hacer por el id pero no sé como hacerlo si la información no viene por POST

Comment: Si pero para poder ayudarte debes colocarlo en la pregunta, porque no se que trae o no **producto** :)

Comment: En la pregunta deje una foto con el modal y lo que me muestra la consola al hacer click en el boton 'ver mas'

Comment: Dices en el post que solo te muestra el nombre de la imagen, en el ejemplo cual es el  nombre de la imagen?

Comment: **$producto['imagen']** es el nombre solo de la imagen? osea **imagen1.jpg** por ejemplo

Comment: Asi es. Ahora cambie la foto en la pregunta para mostrar $producto['imagen'] pero solo me trae el nombre de la foto pero no la muestra.

Comment: Pero en ningun lado se ve una imagen... osea las imagenes tienen formato jpg,png,git, otros... en ningun lado veo eso, como **imagen1.jpg** o **durasno.png**

Comment: en la base de datos no guardo la foto con la extensión del archivo, solo con el nombre

Comment: Ya te doy una respuesta, debes guardar el formato también, sin eso no puedes mostrar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada debes guardar la imagen con su formato (JPG,PNG,GIT,...)
Luego para mostrar la imagen en HTML debes crear la etiqueta IMG

Tienes que mostrar la imagen y no el nombre

Tu código va así

```
<br> <strong>Imagen del producto:</strong> ' . $producto['imagen']
```

Aquí debes poner

```
<br> <strong>Imagen del producto:</strong> <img src="'.$producto['imagen'].'">'
```

De esta manera te tomara la imagen y se verá.

por ultimo colocas tu tamaño a la imagen para que funcione a tu gusto con **width y height**

Comment: Ya me funcionó tu código, me faltaba agregar en la ruta la carpeta img. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!